# CSS styling and transitions in gadget files

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, windows-desktop-gadgets

I have a simple HTML page of nine boxes (divs) which smoothly expand on hover using transitions. I've packaged it into a gadget file for the Windows 7 desktop and now all transitions are lost, even the radii on the boxes are gone.

Do gadget files not support CSS3 transitional statements and styling or do I need to be doing something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using vendor prefixes.

```
-webkit-transform: ;
-moz-transform: ;
-ms-transform: ;
-o-transform: ;
transform: ;

-webkit-border-radius: ;
-moz-border-radius: ;
-ms-border-radius: ;
-o-border-radius: ;
border-radius: ;
```

Comment: Thanks @4dgaurav but that makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the top of your html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

That will let you use more advance CSS.